# Problema no Snippets

Tags: bug

Não sei se é somente na minha maquina, mas não estou conseguindo executar nenhum Snippets na rede, em todas paginas aparece o **http status 503 Service Unavailable**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo outros usuários no chat, o Snippets esta funcionando normal no computador deles.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cheguei a testar em outros navegadores e desinstalei extensões que poderiam vir a influenciar na navegação.

No Opera o html chega a renderizar, porem o javascript não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link dos Snippets: [Aplicar CSS quando duas classes estiverem juntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183414/aplicar-css-quando-duas-classes-estiverem-juntas)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182278

Mesmo problema em outros sites da rede:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fui no meta SOen e tem um tópico la sobre o mesmo erro: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343509/stack-snippets-returning-a-503-service-unavailable-error

---

Acho estranho estar funcionando pra todos menos pra mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Testando no postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

To inconformado rs, o que pode ser?

Comment: Devem ter arrumado porque pra mim está funcionando.

Comment: Sai de casa voltei, e o problema persiste, reiniciei o pc, e ainda assim persistiu ;/

Comment: Acho (?) que o problema e na minha maquina (?) mas ate hoje!! nunca havia ocorrido isso

Comment: Aqui voltou a funcionar